# Why does Rails console tell me that no records exist, but I can't create a record because it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is the strangest thing:

```
> User.count
   (74.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" 
 => 0 
2.0.0p0 :002 > User
 => User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string, confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datetime, unconfirmed_email: string) 
2.0.0p0 :003 > User.create(email: "abc@test.com", password: "test123", password_confirmation: "test123")
   (140.0ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (543.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@test.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<User id: nil, email: "abc@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$s7Ak0w04l3UixRqZbuvrJeLJb/AGD4FxQudSqcvYzDll...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil> 
2.0.0p0 :004 > User.all
  User Load (30.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
 => [] 
> User.where(:email => "abc@test.com")
  User Load (24.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@test.com'
 => []
```

What is happening?

`Rails 3.2.13`

**Edit 1**

The `User.rb` is as vanilla with Devise & Rolify as they come.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_one :store
#  has_many :items, 

end
```

**Edit 2**

Another thing I just tried, per @whit-kimmey's suggestion:

```
> User.create!({email: "abc@test.com", password: "test123", password_confirmation: "test123"}, without_protection: true)
   (1.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (105.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@test.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
```

**Edit 3**

So, if I make the pw 8 characters, it seems to work - which is strange. But that still doesn't answer why it says that the user with that email address already exists?

```
> User.create!({email: "abc@test.com", password: "test-123", password_confirmation: "test-123"}, without_protection: true)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (31.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abc@test.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (19.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = 'EZUGZPp8oEHMPSvExrgX' LIMIT 1
  SQL (742.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "unconfirmed_email", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17) RETURNING "id"  [["confirmation_sent_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 17:47:43 UTC +00:00], ["confirmation_token", "EZUGZPp8oEHMPSvExrgX"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 17:47:43 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "abc@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$0VoGOKvWXhfpOVrut6S6QeM1lkPgOYfq9s4Oo6zg.VMHZoJWTbc8G"], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["name", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["unconfirmed_email", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 03 May 2013 17:47:43 UTC +00:00]]
   (116.5ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 1, email: "abc@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$0VoGOKvWXhfpOVrut6S6QeM1lkPgOYfq9s4Oo6zg.VMH...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-05-03 17:47:43", updated_at: "2013-05-03 17:47:43", name: nil, confirmation_token: "EZUGZPp8oEHMPSvExrgX", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2013-05-03 17:47:43", unconfirmed_email: nil> 
2.0.0p0 :008 >
```

Comment: Can you post the `User` model code?

Comment: It is not that strange because if you look at the line `(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK` the transaction is rolled back. Probably some validation issued.

Comment: You can also have some cycle with before_save/before_create

Comment: Try reloading the console. Can you post u.errors hash? and u.valid?

Comment: This is a brand new console session - after having restarted my machine.

Comment: Also...this is NOT only a validation issue. Perhaps the new record is not being created because of validation issues, but...the question is...why does it say `User.count => 0`, but then it says that user already exists?

Comment: Does it work if you change your password to 8 or more characters?

Comment: Actually...it does. Strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is just executing that query to see if this user aleady exists; it doesn't mean it found one.  You are seeing in the console output the queries that Rails is executing, but this particular one did not find a previously existing user or cause any problems.

Try this:

```
User.create!({email: "abc@test.com", password: "test123", password_confirmation: "test123"}, without_protection: true)
```

Using create! instead of create will help us see the error that ActiveRecord is getting.  Using without_protection will just bypass mass assignment protection just in case that is an issue.

Your results indicate that one of your gems has a failing validation on the length of the password.  Changing the password to be eight characters long will fix the problem.

Comment: The results you posted suggest that you are failing a validation because your password is required to be eight characters and it is only six.  Try giving the user an eight character password (and matching password_confirmation).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say that the user exists anywhere, you're just looking at the queries performed by ActiveRecord to know if the user exists. If you want to get the actual error try this:

```
> user = User.new(email: "abc@test.com", password: "test123", password_confirmation: "test123")
> user.valid?
> user.errors.full_messages
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for validations. You are probably validating for name or some other attributes.

Comment: Even if that were the case, it isn't....I don't have any validations on my `User` model, why would it say `User.count = 0` but when I try to create the record it says that it exists?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to an uncommitted transaction, so if the transaction is still not committed, then use below command to commit it:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.commit_db_transaction
```